# cannot ping ubuntu server after changing the IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, ip

The problem I am facing now is that I have a GPU server running Ubuntu 16.04, and I connect through the *ssh*. but after a sudden fail of power source, I turned on the machine again and found that the IP address has changed.
 
I tried to connect using the new IP address(using the command "ifconfig" in the terminal), but failed. So I pinged the server and there were no response.
As I am not very familiar with internet protocols, can anybody tell me what I should do to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post an output of the error message and the used command. Are there firewalls between you and the GPU server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I later solved this problem, actually it was silly. The reason was actually that the server has to login to the student account to have internet access. Very oddly, the server is only accessible by vpn only if it has internet access.

When using the ip inside the school, you can always connect, but outside of school, you have to first log the server in.